# Change localization for a UIButton on Storyboard

Tags: ios, localization, ios7, xcode5

I have few elements on the a storyboard like labels, UIViews, images and a button. I wish to localize the button just for English language and wish to hide it in other languages.

I selected the button on the storyboard and tried changing its localization property to English. But I got a warning saying that the change would be applied to entire storyboard and the change cannot be undone.

By this I understand, changing the localization property for one element may affect all the other elements as well. Has anyone worked on similar scenario before? How do I handle the localization change for just one UIElement?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question, but why do you not test the language in your code and set its alpha to 0 if not English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test the current language of the application and hide your outlets for a particular language :

```
NSString *myLanguage = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];

if (![myLanguage  isEqualToString:@"en"]) 
{
    // For example, hide outlets here when the language is not English 
}
```